# Creating a Pathfinder for a simple game in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, console-application, path-finding

I have a simple coin collector game which is passed an array and must go from players x and y position in the array to a coin x and y position in the array without going on array values "w" and chrw(9068). "w" represent the blue water and chrw(9068) is the grey walls (this will make more sense when you look at the image.

I am doing this because i kepp ending up in situations like this where it is impossible to reach the coin or the player is spawned ina boxed in area.

[image: I am doing this because i kepp ending up in situations like this where it is impossible to reach the coin or the player is spawned ina boxed in area.]

I have browsed online but can't seem to find much explaining them and pretty much nothing in vb.net that isn't outdated.

Comment: You could search for "vb.net Dijkstra's Algorithm" if you don't want to program a pathfinding algorithm yourself. Just because an algorithm is a few decades old doesn't mean it isn't good enough.

Comment: It is that the methods these programs use don't work anymore as i for example tried many A* pathfinders but none worked with current vb.net, thanks for your advice anyway